# Bound and resolution of a raster in Julia

Tags: julia, raster

I am looking if Julia could be a good alternative to Python for my work. I use raster data so I plan to use ArchGDAL. However after searching on the web, I do not find how to find bound and compute resolution of a raster. Do I miss something ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question might benefit from some clarification. But if I were to guess, perhaps https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageQualityIndexes.jl might help?

Comment: Thx for the comment.
I have found the answer: ArchGDAL.geotransform() give the information I need

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can find the ArchGDAL docs here: https://yeesian.com/ArchGDAL.jl/stable/ and the specific function that will allow you to find the bound and complete the resolution of a raster: https://yeesian.com/ArchGDAL.jl/stable/search/?q=geotransform